# My app crashes even if there is no error in the code

Tags: android, debugging

I am new to android programming and i was trying to make an app for managing my daily tasks. now my application needs to switch between activities, it starts normally on the first activity, but when i click the button to go to the other activity the app just crashes. i am debugging directly to my phone (Galaxy s3).

I thought the logcat output might be useful as i noticed it helped a lot during the other questions.

```
09-24 05:49:14.807: D/dalvikvm(9062): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 137K, 4% free 12835K/13255K, paused 25ms
09-24 05:49:14.807: I/dalvikvm-heap(9062): Grow heap (frag case) to 13.065MB for 379472-byte allocation
09-24 05:49:14.837: D/dalvikvm(9062): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 4% free 13205K/13639K, paused 11ms
09-24 05:49:14.862: D/AbsListView(9062): Get MotionRecognitionManager
09-24 05:49:16.102: D/CLIPBOARD(9062): Hide Clipboard dialog at Starting input: finished by someone else... !
09-24 05:49:22.282: D/AndroidRuntime(9062): Shutting down VM
09-24 05:49:22.282: W/dalvikvm(9062): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c661f8)
09-24 05:49:22.297: E/AndroidRuntime(9062): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-24 05:49:22.297: E/AndroidRuntime(9062): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.dailyplanner/com.example.dailyplanner.new_task}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #24: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
09-24 05:49:22.297: E/AndroidRuntime(9062):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1970)
09-24 05:49:22.297: E/AndroidRuntime(9062):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
09-24 05:49:22.297: E/AndroidRuntime(9062):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128)
09-24 05:49:22.297: E/AndroidRuntime(9062):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
09-24 05:49:22.297: E/AndroidRuntime(9062):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-24 05:49:22.297: E/AndroidRuntime(9062):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-24 05:49:22.297: E/AndroidRuntime(9062):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
09-24 05:49:22.297: E/AndroidRuntime(9062):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-24 05:49:22.297: E/AndroidRuntime(9062):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-24 05:49:22.297: E/AndroidRuntime(9062):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
09-24 05:49:22.297: E/AndroidRuntime(9062):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
09-24 05:49:22.297: E/AndroidRuntime(9062):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-24 05:49:22.297: E/AndroidRuntime(9062): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #24: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
09-24 05:49:22.297: E/AndroidRuntime(9062):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getLayoutDimension(TypedArray.java:491)
09-24 05:49:22.297: E/AndroidRuntime(9062):     at android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.setBaseAttributes(ViewGroup.java:5331)
09-24 05:49:22.297: E/AndroidRuntime(9062):     at android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.<init>(ViewGroup.java:5452)
09-24 05:49:22.297: E/AndroidRuntime(9062):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:1064)
09-24 05:49:22.297: E/AndroidRuntime(9062):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.generateLayoutParams(RelativeLayout.java:933)
09-24 05:49:22.297: E/AndroidRuntime(9062):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.generateLayoutParams(RelativeLayout.java:69)
09-24 05:49:22.297: E/AndroidRuntime(9062):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:741)
09-24 05:49:22.297: E/AndroidRuntime(9062):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
09-24 05:49:22.297: E/AndroidRuntime(9062):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
09-24 05:49:22.297: E/AndroidRuntime(9062):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
09-24 05:49:22.297: E/AndroidRuntime(9062):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:280)
09-24 05:49:22.297: E/AndroidRuntime(9062):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1892)
09-24 05:49:22.297: E/AndroidRuntime(9062):     at com.example.dailyplanner.new_task.onCreate(new_task.java:23)
09-24 05:49:22.297: E/AndroidRuntime(9062):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4562)
09-24 05:49:22.297: E/AndroidRuntime(9062):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1053)
09-24 05:49:22.297: E/AndroidRuntime(9062):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1934)
09-24 05:49:22.297: E/AndroidRuntime(9062):     ... 11 more
09-24 05:49:22.317: D/dalvikvm(9062): GC_CONCURRENT freed 164K, 3% free 13459K/13831K, paused 1ms+2ms
09-24 05:49:22.322: E/SQLiteDatabase(9062): close() was never explicitly called on database '/data/data/com.example.dailyplanner/databases/MyDB' 
09-24 05:49:22.322: E/SQLiteDatabase(9062): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
09-24 05:49:22.322: E/SQLiteDatabase(9062):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:2064)
09-24 05:49:22.322: E/SQLiteDatabase(9062):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1118)
09-24 05:49:22.322: E/SQLiteDatabase(9062):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1075)
09-24 05:49:22.322: E/SQLiteDatabase(9062):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1051)
09-24 05:49:22.322: E/SQLiteDatabase(9062):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1154)
09-24 05:49:22.322: E/SQLiteDatabase(9062):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1147)
09-24 05:49:22.322: E/SQLiteDatabase(9062):     at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:860)
09-24 05:49:22.322: E/SQLiteDatabase(9062):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:222)
09-24 05:49:22.322: E/SQLiteDatabase(9062):     at com.example.dailyplanner.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
09-24 05:49:22.322: E/SQLiteDatabase(9062):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4562)
09-24 05:49:22.322: E/SQLiteDatabase(9062):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1053)
09-24 05:49:22.322: E/SQLiteDatabase(9062):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1934)
09-24 05:49:22.322: E/SQLiteDatabase(9062):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
09-24 05:49:22.322: E/SQLiteDatabase(9062):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128)
09-24 05:49:22.322: E/SQLiteDatabase(9062):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
09-24 05:49:22.322: E/SQLiteDatabase(9062):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-24 05:49:22.322: E/SQLiteDatabase(9062):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-24 05:49:22.322: E/SQLiteDatabase(9062):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
09-24 05:49:22.322: E/SQLiteDatabase(9062):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-24 05:49:22.322: E/SQLiteDatabase(9062):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-24 05:49:22.322: E/SQLiteDatabase(9062):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
09-24 05:49:22.322: E/SQLiteDatabase(9062):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
09-24 05:49:22.322: E/SQLiteDatabase(9062):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`
```

here is my android manifest:

```
<manifest package="com.example.dailyplanner"

    android:versionName="1.0" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res
/android" android:versionCode="1">



    <uses-sdk

        android:minSdkVersion="9"

        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />



<application

    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"

    android:label="@string/app_name"

    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" >

    <activity

        android:name=".MainActivity"

        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"

        android:screenOrientation="portrait" 

        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">

        <intent-filter>

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />


            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".new_task"/>
</application>
```

`

and here's the code of the 2 java files:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("MyDB", MODE_PRIVATE, null );
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Data1 (Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, text VARCHAR, time TIME, date DATE)");



        Button nTaskBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nTask);
        nTaskBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent nTaskScreen = new Intent(MainActivity.this, new_task.class);



                startActivity(nTaskScreen);



            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

second file:

```
import android.R.string;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.net.UrlQuerySanitizer.ValueSanitizer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.renderscript.Sampler.Value;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
public class new_task extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.new_task);

        TextView timeTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeTxt);
        TextView dateTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dateTxt);

        Button btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {



            }
        });



        Button btnSetTime = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSetTime);
        btnSetTime.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {




            }
        });



        }


    }
```

any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: try using sqlitedatabasehelper class as in http://codinglookseasy.blogspot.in/2012/08/sqlite-database.html or http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the logcat error clearly, especially this line..

```
09-24 05:49:22.297: E/AndroidRuntime(9062): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #24: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
```

Comment: totally missed that line, i immediately saw it when i posted the question but i couldn't remove it again

Comment: yep. a old tag on the xml from an image view that i had "deleted" caused the problem, cleared the project, deleted the old xml tags and now it works.
now i need to work now on the problem with the db though.

Comment: Renjith can i contact you privately, i need to ask you for some more help

Answer (score 1):

The logcat output explains the problems. First, it appears that in the file `res/layout/activity_main`, there is (at least) one view that does not have a required `android:layout_width` attribute.

Another problem is that you are opening a data base in `MainActivity.onCreate` and you are never closing it. You need to close it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to supply necessary attributes.layout_height and layout_width to your layout